# Find out total day sale based on same day

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have following data in my Sale table:

```
   Staff_Code  | Tran_Date  |  Morning_Sale | Night_Sale | Total_Sale
       S01     | 2013-05-01 |     50.00     |   300.00   |  350.00
       S02     | 2013-05-01 |     10.00     |   70.00    |   80.00
       S01     | 2013-05-02 |     100.00    |   20.00    |  120.00
```

I want to add 1 more column "total_Day_Sale" to know the daily total sale,the format as following table:

```
   Staff_Code  | Tran_Date  |  Morning_Sale | Night_Sale | Total_Sale | Total_Day_Sale
       S01     | 2013-05-01 |     50.00     |   300.00   |  350.00    |   430.00  
       S02     | 2013-05-01 |     10.00     |   70.00    |   80.00    |   430.00
       S01     | 2013-05-02 |     100.00    |   20.00    |  120.00    |   120.00
```

I was trying the following code but not as result I expected!

```
SELECT Tran_Date,Morning_Sale,Night_Sale,Morning_Sale + Night_Sale As 'Total_Sale', 
sum(Morning_Sale)+sum(Night_Sale ) As 'Total_Day_Sale' FROM Sale 
WHERE Tran_Date=Tran_Date
```

Is it possible to do that? Thanks

Comment: Why are there two rows for the same date? How are these divergence?

Comment: Is Total_Sale a column in the base table, or something you calculate in the query? First you show it in the table, but then in your query it is calculated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the easiest way is to use a SUM() Over PARTITION BY Clause.

```
SELECT Staff_Code,
        Tran_Date,
        Morning_Sale,
        Night_Sale,
        Total_Sale,
SUM(Total_Sale)  OVER (PARTITION BY Tran_Date) AS Total_Day_Sale
FROM #DailyTotals
```

Output:

```
Staff_Code Tran_Date  Morning_Sale Night_Sale  Total_Sale  Total_Day_Sale
---------- ---------- ------------ ----------- ----------- --------------
       S01 2013-05-01 50           300         350         430
       S02 2013-05-01 10           70          80          430
       S01 2013-05-02 100          20          120         120

(3 row(s) affected)
```

Hope this helps! (P.S.-> As I have used INT as the datatype for my temp table hence the zeroes after decimal are gone. This query will work for you as your base data is already decimal/float I assume.

Comment: The PARTITION BY and ORDER BY clause has been of great help in such scenarios, can be used along with SUM() , DENSE_RANK() etc. to get some pretty cool results.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it in a correlated subquery,

```
SELECT  Tran_Date,
        Morning_Sale,
        Night_Sale,
        Morning_Sale + Night_Sale As 'Total_Sale', 
        (
            SELECT  SUM(Morning_Sale + Night_Sale)
            FROM    Sale b
            WHERE   a.Tran_Date = b.Tran_Date AND
                    b.Tran_Date = _Tran_Date
        )   As 'Total_Day_Sale' 
FROM    Sale a
WHERE   Tran_Date = _Tran_Date
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b6c4f/1)

using `JOIN`

```
SELECT  a.Tran_Date,
        a.Morning_Sale,
        a.Night_Sale,
        a.Morning_Sale + a.Night_Sale As 'Total_Sale', 
        b.Total_Day_Sale
FROM    Sale a
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT  Tran_Date, SUM(Morning_Sale + Night_Sale) Total_Day_Sale
            FROM    Sale 
            WHERE   Tran_Date = _Tran_Date
            GROUP   BY Tran_Date
        ) b   ON a.Tran_Date = b.Tran_Date
WHERE   a.Tran_Date = _Tran_Date
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b6c4f/3)

As an advice, the parameter name should be different from the name of the column.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, the SQLFiddle Demo is very useful

Answer (score 1):

Don't store it, but use a view instead, and then join your table with the view. If you are using SQL Server, you can use a CTE instead of a view:

```
WITH DailyTotal AS
(SELECT Tran_Date, sum(Morning_Sale + Night_Sale) AS "Total_Day_Sale"
FROM Sale
GROUP BY Tran_Date)
SELECT Sale.Tran_Date, Morning_Sale, Night_Sale,
       Morning_Sale + Night_Sale As "Total_Sale", Total_Day_Sale
FROM Sale, DailyTotal
WHERE Sale.Tran_Date = DailyTotal.Tran_Date;
```

If you need very high read performance, you may need to materialize the view. But start with this.

Answer (score 0):

You can resolve this problem by using triggers. Whenever a new value is inputted, trigger adds it's value to the Total_Day_Sale. What is this database?

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't want to change your table that way. It would require you to update each entry for the each day every time a new entry was entered for that day--to store the new total total. I'd use another table to store the daily total, which would only require one update whenever you add a new daily entry:

```
Date       | Total Sale
2013-05-01 | 480.00
```